# Google Admin SDK 403 Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: google-admin-sdk, rate-limiting

We are working with Google's **Admin SDK API**. We get a lot of 403 (Rate limit exceeded) errors when we execute more than 2 threads making batch requests to Google's servers.

We have changed the Rate Limit of Requests per second in the project admin panel but it seems to have no effect. As google recommends in https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits we have tried with one user's credential per thread.

How many requests per second can we actually send?

Is there any way apart from contacting Google to increase that Rate limit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit quota request to increase you query limit by going to API console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/‎
).  Go to the quota pane and click "Request more" next to Admin SDK.  A form should show up, and you can submit your request.  Make sure you include your calculation and justification.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably requesting new access tokens for every request. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24211132/1135732